# SQL Server Duplicate Records + add time to each new row

Tags: sql-server, duplicate-data

Below is a CTE I am currently using to count how many times it took to send a transmission over a given period of time. The CTE works by sharing the time to send in seconds (HT.ElapsedTime) by 60. This then produces a value such as 4, 6, 10 etc.

### CTE_Duplicated Records_Count

```
WITH CTE_Duplicate_Records_Count AS
(
SELECT
        H.ObjectGuid AS Transmission_ID
    ,   H.TRDateTime AS [Transmission Start Time]
    ,   HT.[ElapsedTime] / 60 AS [totalCount]
FROM [dbo].History AS H (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].HistoryTRX AS HT (NOLOCK) ON H.handle = HT.handle
```

The main select statement pulls through the necessary columns from the transmission table as well as joins the CTE above onto it where the transmission id's match.

### Main Select Statement

```
SELECT

    -- Transmission Table
    ---------------------
        H.ObjectGuid AS Transmission_ID
    ,   CAST(H.[TRDateTime] AS DateTime) AS [Transmission Start Date]
    ,   CAST(DATEADD(second, HT.ElapsedTime, H.TRDateTime) AS DateTime) AS [Transmission End Date]
    ,   HT.[ElapsedTime] AS [Time taken to send in seconds]
    ,   HT.GoodPageCount AS Pages
    ,   HT.[ChannelUsed]

    -- CTE Duplicate Records Count 
    --------------------------
    ,   DRC.Transmission_ID
    ,   DRC.totalCount

FROM [dbo].History AS H (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].HistoryTRX AS HT (NOLOCK) ON H.handle = HT.handle

INNER JOIN CTE_Duplicate_Records_Count DRC ON Transmission_ID = H.ObjectGuid

WHERE 
    DRC.Transmission_ID = 'BFE008F7-F9D6-44D8-B06C-916875FC0F6D'

ORDER BY H.ObjectGuid DESC
```

As an example the above select statement produces something like so:

```
TransmissionID
Transmission Start Date
Transmission End Date
Time Taken in seconds
Pages
TotalCount

BBBBBB
2015-08-04 12:42:45
2015-08-04 12:56:45
840
5
14 (minutes)
```

The desired result is for each record to be duplicated by the totalCount number. I.e. the above record would be duplicated 14 times. Also for each row duplicated I would like to add 60 seconds to the start time.

Any ideas as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: You seem fairly savvy, so I'll just give a nudge.  Look into recursive CTEs and using TotalCount to set the number of recursions.